# Create rainbow table from words in text file with Python

Tags: python

I'm looking to write a script to parse through a text file and create md4 hashes of every word in the text file. I want the output to be sent to a different text file. This is what I have so far:

```
import hashlib
passwd = open(list.txt)
lines = passwd.readlines()
passwd.close()

hash_object = hashlib.md4(passwd.encode()
print(hash_object.hexdigest())
```

Comment: can you provide example of list.txt, how do you define word, and what kind of output do you want (like all words in one line, every word in new line)?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, try this:

```
# Create NTLM Rainbow Table from word dictionary
import hashlib,binascii

with open('NTLM_Rainbow_Table.txt', 'w') as result: #What my output file will be called; in current directory
    for word in open('dictionary.txt').read().split(): #what my dictionary file is called; in current directory
        h = hashlib.new('md4', word.encode('utf-16le')).digest() #Before hashing the passwords are stored as UTF_16_LE.
        result.write(word + ':' + binascii.hexlify(h) + '\n')
```

I am currently running Python 2.7.13 in Kali Linux.

Credits to @DRPK. Your script rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD4

with open('result.txt', 'w') as result:
    for word in open('list.txt').read().split():
        h = MD4.new()
        h.update(bytes(word, 'utf-8'))
        result.write(word + ':' + h.hexdigest() + '\n')
```

Your "question" is not clear, so I'm guessing here...

For an input file like:

```
password
sample
hello
```

The output file (*result.txt*) will be like:

```
password:8a9d093f14f8701df17732b2bb182c74
sample:acc4d5991ef52ee9ced7ae04a3e79dbb
hello:866437cb7a794bce2b727acc0362ee27
```

Credits to @DRPK

Answer (score 0):

For MD4 hash you need Crypto module.

you can install this package by pip command like this:

```
pip install Crypto
```

Or download it from:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto
```

Lets go for main code:

```
from Crypto.Hash import MD4

your_file_path = "your_target_file"  # change this item with your own address ...
your_result_path = "your_result_file" # change this item with your own address ...

def md4_of_each_words(your_file_path):


    md4_hash = MD4.new()

    with open(your_file_path, "r") as raw_data:
        read_raw_data = raw_data.read()

    make_a_list = read_raw_data.split('\n')

    for lines in make_a_list:

        if not lines.replace(" ", '').replace("\t", "") == "":
            words_list = lines.split(' ')

            for words in words_list:

                if not words.replace(" ", "").replace("\t", "") == "":

                    # Calculate MD4 Hash For Each Valid Words
                    md4_hash.update(words)
                    last_md4 = md4_hash.hexdigest() + "\n"

                    with open(your_result_path, "a") as md4_list:
                        md4_list.write(words + last_md4)

                else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass

    return "Completed."

md4_of_each_words(your_file_path)
```

Good Luck